# Match Against Doctrine Extension configuration

Tags: symfony, doctrine, match-against

I'm trying to make match against doctrine extension work but i get error with doctrine configuration file. I got `Unrecognized option "dql" under "doctrine.orm"` . How to propely use symfony 4 + doctrine + match against extension?

Match against file + conf https://gist.github.com/ZeBigDuck/1234419#file-addfulltextindexescommand-php

```
parameters:
    # Adds a fallback DATABASE_URL if the env var is not set.
    # This allows you to run cache:warmup even if your
    # environment variables are not available yet.
    # You should not need to change this value.
    env(DATABASE_URL): ''

doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    orm:
      dql:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
#        string_functions:
#          MATCH_AGAINST: App\Extension\Doctrine\MatchAgainst
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
      entity_managers:
        default:
          dql:
            string_functions:
              MATCH_AGAINST: App\Extension\Doctrine\MatchAgainst
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
    orm:
       auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
       naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
       auto_mapping: true
       dql:
         string_functions:
            MATCH_AGAINST: App\Extension\Doctrine\MatchAgainst
```

*EDIT.. It should be something like this (not tested):*

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
      # configure these for your database server
      driver: 'pdo_mysql'
      server_version: '5.7'
      charset: utf8mb4
      default_table_options:
        charset: utf8mb4
        collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

      url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    orm:
      auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
      naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
      auto_mapping: true
      dql:
        string_functions:
          MATCH_AGAINST: App\Extension\Doctrine\MatchAgainst
      mappings:
        App:
          is_bundle: false
          type: annotation
          dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
          prefix: 'App\Entity'
          alias: App
```

Comment: Thanks for help but i get another error `Unrecognized options "auto_generate_proxy_classes, naming_strategy, auto_mapping, mappings" under "doctrine.orm.entity_managers.default.dql"`

Comment: you can not use them under entity_managers: default: dql. Let me edit the answer

Comment: Sadly again another error `Unrecognized options "is_bundle, type, dir, prefix, alias" under "doctrine.orm.entity_managers.default"` please help me with that

Comment: can you change entity_managers to mappings and default to App

Comment: You mean this https://pastebin.com/YkPbCBew ? I didn't get errors, site run, but i will check is it works.

Comment: yes but App should be capital letter. I don't know if it'll matter

Comment: Corrected app to App. I get mysql errors, it looks like its' working. It really helps me! Thank's a lot! I'll never do that on my own.

Comment: One more thing i have `->where("MATCH_AGAINST (p.primarytitle, :search 'IN BOOLEAN MODE') > 0.0")` but i don't know what `> 0.0` mean. What is it. I didnt see in raw sql.

Comment: I also don't know how to compare, i want do MATCH p.primaryTitle against :search how to do that?

Comment: honestly, I have never worked with MATCH_AGAINST before. Take a look at https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/90/how-to-implement-fulltext-search-mysql-with-doctrine-and-symfony-3 maybe this will help you.

Comment: Just a note that on my Symfony 5.2, the `dql` block only works under a connection definition

Comment: @Bigdot i don't get it work under Symfony 5.4 ... Can you give me a sample code what you mean with the connection definition.

Comment: @M.F I don't use symfony anymore and have no easy way to test this right now. Check the configuration reference https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/reference/configuration/doctrine.html . From what i can recall you need to put the `dql` inside one of the blocks in `connections:` even though it's not documented